# How to get images for multiple location from the panorama?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, panoramio

How to get all images from the panorama by sending multiple latitude, longitude at a time.

I want to show the panorama images on my site and for the same I did the follwing

I am able to get images from the panorama by sending tag & lat lng  for one location only as:

```
 'http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=public&tag=pune&from=0&to=20&size=medium&mapfilter=true'
```

it gives me 20 images for `pune` `tag`

By using lat & lng I used the follwing URL to the Images:

```
'http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=public&minx=' . (73.856743 - 0.045) . '&miny=' . (18.520430 - 0.045) . '&maxx=' . 73.856743 . '&maxy=' . 18.520430 . '&from=0&to=1&size=medium';
```

it gives me 20 images for `pune` location which is having `lat = 18.520430` and `lng = 73.856743`

Is there way to get the images by sending `multiple` **tags** or **lat lng** i.e for multiple location at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to get photos of two tag or two different locations at a time.

In JavaScript code You can change many things.

this Panoramio JavaScript API widget create a bounding box around a lat/long pair and then returning all photos with in those bounds.

Another type of Panoramio JavaScript API widget in which you can also change background color with [example and code is here](http://codespk.blogspot.com/2013/10/panoramio-javascript-api-widget-example.html).

I have made a [blogspot page](http://discoverworldz.blogspot.com/) where i have created many Panoramio JavaScript and HTML API widgets.

It does not show in composing mood.It show after publishing.

```
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" trbidi="on">
<script src="https://ssl.panoramio.com/wapi/wapi.js?v=1&amp;hl=en"></script>
<div id="wapiblock" style="float: right; margin: 10px 15px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myRequest = {
  'tag': 'kahna',
  'rect': {'sw': {'lat': -30, 'lng': 10.5}, 'ne': {'lat': 50.5, 'lng': 30}}
};
  var myOptions = {
  'width': 300,
  'height': 200
};
var wapiblock = document.getElementById('wapiblock');
var photo_widget = new panoramio.PhotoWidget('wapiblock', myRequest, myOptions);
photo_widget.setPosition(0);
</script>
</div>
```